# Index list (recursion)

Tags: python, list, recursion, indexing, typeerror

I need help with this school assignment.

I am very new to Python and programming, especially to recursion.

I need to write a function in Python called ind(e, L); the question of the assignment is, how often is e in the L list and where the e is displayed for the first in L. I cannot use the index function.

The code I have made so far:

```
def ind(e, L):
    if e in L:
        if e == 0 or "" or []:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + ind(L[0:])

assert ind(42, [24, 31, 42, 66, 24, 100]) == 2
assert ind("hi", ["oh", "hi", "there"]) == 1
```

I do understand how lists work, but I don't see the point how this will work with recursion.
I also often receive the error: `TypeError: ind() missing 1 required positional argument: 'L'`

Can someone please explain how this works and why I am getting this TypeError?
Your help will be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You're calling ind() with one argument on line 6. It needs two; what are you trying to do with that call?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate that. The function ind() should be giving the position of index where e is displayed for the first in L. Hopefully you can help me out. 
Sorry for asking these stupid questions.

Comment: If you don't have to use recursion, you could try looping through the list, like this: `for item in L:`. Otherwise, you will have to change the whole function: I assume you're trying to check if the next set of items in the list contain `e`, however to do this you need to change `L[0:]` to `L[1:]` and add `L` as a parameter: `ind(L[1:], L)`. Even then you'll also need to add a `return 0` to the end of the function so that it won't return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to give the function that will output the correct answer as your solution require a lot of tweaking.

Please see the nested function below. I am using a helper function since I did not want to add additional parameters being passed into ind. This function will have a Time Complexity O(n) since we are just iterating through the list via recursion.

This function will return a **list** with length = 2.

**list**[0] --> how often e variable appeared in list L.

**list**[1] --> the first index in L (if) e appeared. If not, it will return None.

```
def ind(e, L):
    if not L:
        return [0, None]

    # I am using the helper function because I did not want to modify the parameters
    # being passed into the ind function (i.e., wanted to keep ind(e, L))

    def helper(index=0, count=0, found=False, firstindex=None):
        if index == len(L):
            # firstindex is set to None if count == 0
            return [count, firstindex]

        if e == L[index]:
            if not found:
                return helper(index + 1, count + 1, True, index)
            return helper(index + 1, count + 1, found, firstindex)

        return helper(index + 1, count, found, firstindex)

    return helper()

count1, firstIndex1 = ind(42, [24, 31, 42, 66, 24, 100])
count2, firstIndex2 = ind("hi", ["oh", "hi", "there"])
```

Comment: @BlueTiger - Any feedback/upvotes would be highly appreciated. Thank you! :-)